# What is the main difference between simple present and present perfect?

Tags: tense, present-perfect, present-tense, present-simple

I'm really confused between **simple present** and **present perfect**. Is there anything to help me understand the differences?

Comment: You could try searching this site and reading the many answers to questions like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Simple Present**

The simple present tense is used for:

1. An action that happens regularly

   - I **take** the train for office
2. Facts

   - An octopus **has** eight limbs
3. Habitual actions/ occurrences

   - I **sleep** for 20 hours everyday

**Present Perfect**

The present perfect tense is used for:

1. An action or state that began in the past and continued to the present time

   - She **has worked** in the bank for five years.
2. An action repeated in an unspecified period between the past and now.

   - I **have seen** that movie six times
3. An action completed in the very recent past

   - I **have finished** my homework